# javascript array into object with same key names

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an unusual problem to solve here. I have an array of Guids

```
[
 "c01f8237-72c8-4fa6-9c53-1915750385aa",
 "2c8a471b-c408-436c-81b1-3f3867d8ffb4",
 "27a44d46-12bd-4784-ceed-57ada31b0e33"
]
```

This array has to be transformed into:

```
   {
     id: "c01f8237-72c8-4fa6-9c53-1915750385aa",
     id: "2c8a471b-c408-436c-81b1-3f3867d8ffb4",
     id: "27a44d46-12bd-4784-ceed-57ada31b0e33"
   }
```

I know that shouldn't be done, but unfortunately cannot control the back end part. Any idea?

Thanks

Comment: Same key cannot be there in the object more than once

Comment: I know that very well. But as I said in the question, unfortunately the back end that receives the object hasn't been built in a standard way and I cannot change it.

Comment: @Mauro74 what he means is that it is not possible in javascript. However, what **exactly** is your back end expecting? Backends expect serialization formats, not javascript. The above is not valid JSON, is not not expecting json?

Comment: So you don't want it transformed into an object, but rather serialized into a string in that form. Seems like a very simple task if that's the case. What's the problem?

Comment: It sounds like the back end is not really expecting "JSON", but is really just using something trivial like String.split() to build an array that it then loops over. If so, you're stuck using string concatenation to build the input.

Comment: Are you sure you don't mean that you need the GUIDs as the key? Also if you just want to build what you have shown, which is not JSON, it would be trivial to build that string with a for loop. Please clarify how this going to be used so we can provide better help

Answer (score 2):

The whole point of a dictionary key is that it uniquely maps to some value. Your desired output attempts to duplicate a key and therefore is neither possible nor does it make sense.

If you're passing this to a backend (as you suggest), then of course you can manually build a string to pass over the wire that duplicates keys in the payload, but you won't be able to actually do it in JavaScript first. You'll have to manually build the string.

Also note that you can call this format whatever you want, but **you can't call it JSON** and you can't use JSON libraries to build it (because *it's not JSON*). If your API expects a custom format, then you need to write code to build that custom format.

Comment: I know that very well. But as I said in the question, unfortunately the back end that receives the object hasn't been built in a standard way and I cannot change it.

Comment: If you're passing this to a backend, then of course you can manually build a string to pass over the wire that duplicates keys in the JSON payload, but you won't be able to actually do it in JavaScript first.

Answer (score 2):

If all you want is a string just do something like

```
var str = '{' + idArray.map(function(id) { 
       return "id: "+id
   }).join(',\n')+'}';
```

I have no idea what mime type you would put on that though since its not valid JSON.

Comment: Or just: `str = '{id:"' + idArray.join('", id:"') + '"}'` Probably just `text/plain` MIME. And you're missing the quotes around the IDs in the result.

Comment: This answers the question, as non-sensical as it may be